# How to check if two tensors are equal

Tags: tensorflow.js

Given two tensors of any rank, how can I tell if they both are the same, have I to set my propre solution of there is any kind of implementation of this comparaison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if two tensors are equal, one can use `tf.equal`. But it returns a tensor, a result of a bitwise operation. This tensor elements are whether 1 or 0. Therefore computing the sum of the later tensor should give the number of elements of the tensor if both tensors are equal.

```js
    const a = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);
    const b = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);
    const c = a.equal(b).sum().dataSync()[0]
    
    console.log(c)
    
    c === a.shape.reduce((a,b) => a *= b) ? console.log("true") : console.log("false")
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.12.4/tf.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: or we can simply use all(tf.equal(a,b))

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody needs it for python, the following expression can be used:

```
tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(a,b))
```